# Regular Expression to reformat a US phone number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to reformat (replace, not validate - there are many references for validating) a phone number for display in Javascript. Here's an example of some of the data:

- 123 4567890
- (123) 456-7890
- (123)456-7890
- 123 456 7890
- 123.456.7890
- (blank/null)
- 1234567890

Is there an easy way to use a regular expression to do this? I'm looking for the best way to do this. Is there a better way?

I want to reformat the number to the following: `(123) 456-7890`

Comment: And which one of those is your target format?

Comment: This one: (123) 456-7890

Comment: I'd say just strip all non-digit characters then take three substrings.

Comment: @Wiseguy please post that as an answer (with an example), since that's really what OP should do.

Comment: You also need to specify how each one of the accepted formats maps to the target format, which is not obvious at all if the input is null. Unless you are willing to use an extra conditional to weed that case out.

Comment: What about international numbers.

Answer (score 373, accepted):

Assuming you want the format "`(123) 456-7890`":

```javascript
function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumberString) {
  var cleaned = ('' + phoneNumberString).replace(/\D/g, '');
  var match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
  if (match) {
    return '(' + match[1] + ') ' + match[2] + '-' + match[3];
  }
  return null;
}
```

Here's a version that allows the optional `+1` international code:

```
function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumberString) {
  var cleaned = ('' + phoneNumberString).replace(/\D/g, '');
  var match = cleaned.match(/^(1|)?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
  if (match) {
    var intlCode = (match[1] ? '+1 ' : '');
    return [intlCode, '(', match[2], ') ', match[3], '-', match[4]].join('');
  }
  return null;
}
formatPhoneNumber('+12345678900') // => "+1 (234) 567-8900"
formatPhoneNumber('2345678900')   // => "(234) 567-8900"
```

Comment: Perfect; thank you! However, I changed `return (!m) ? null` to `return (!m) ? ""` after adding this function.

Comment: A nice lesson in how to approach a problem. I was trying to think how to match all possible cases--you eliminate the irrelevant and see if there's a match. Very nice.

Comment: FYI this doesn't work for numbers like +1555-555-5555

Comment: `'' + phoneNumberString` is the same as `phoneNumberString`... It's already a string.

Comment: @YungGun unless someone calls the function with a number, e.g. `formatPhoneNumber(8001231234)`

Comment: @maerics True, seems kind of weird to use do that but it's possible. I suppose it is safer to include `'' + phoneNumberString`

Comment: There are [country calling codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes) other than `+1`. To account for that replace `^(1|)` with `^(\d|)` in the regex and `'+1 '` with `'+${match[1]} '` on the `var intlCode` line.

Comment: @AdamZerner true but phone numbers in other countries don't all have exactly ten digits, so the formatting here doesn't apply internationally.

Comment: @maerics Ah ok, that makes sense.

Answer (score 46):

```js
var x = '301.474.4062';
    
x = x.replace(/\D+/g, '')
     .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2-$3');

alert(x);
```

Comment: Thank you Sean, I like your short simple inline solution.

Comment: Thanks for this! I changed it to `x = x.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '')
     .replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '+$1 ($2) $3-$4');` to work for adding '+1' in front of the phone number for example

Comment: Thanks! this is just i needed

Answer (score 40):

Possible solution:

```
function normalize(phone) {
    //normalize string and remove all unnecessary characters
    phone = phone.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");

    //check if number length equals to 10
    if (phone.length == 10) {
        //reformat and return phone number
        return phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");
    }

    return null;
}

var phone = '(123)4567890';
phone = normalize(phone); //(123) 456-7890
```

Answer (score 14):

This answer borrows from maerics' answer. It differs primarily in that it accepts partially entered phone numbers and formats the parts that have been entered.

```javascript
phone = value.replace(/\D/g, '');
const match = phone.match(/^(\d{1,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})$/);
if (match) {
  phone = `${match[1]}${match[2] ? ' ' : ''}${match[2]}${match[3] ? '-' : ''}${match[3]}`;
}
return phone
```

Comment: This works as you type, adding in the desired format from the source poster. After 1.5 hours of searching, I'm happy I tried this one!

Comment: I added parentheses around the area code if that helps: `(${match[1]}${match[2] ? ') ' : ''}${match[2]}${match[3] ? '-' : ''}${match[3]}`

Comment: Actually the problem is then you can't backspace over the '-' or the space from mid-string. You need to prevent reformatting when the user is backspacing (e.g. `newstring.length < oldstring.length` OR to track the cursor position and figure out when the user has just backspaced over those delimiters e.g. `if (cursorPosition === 4 && numericString.length > 3)`

Comment: In my react code I get around this by internally only storing the number entered and then formatting what gets placed in the field. So the backspace removes the previous character in the actual value, not the displayed value.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using this function to format US numbers.

```
function formatUsPhone(phone) {

    var phoneTest = new RegExp(/^((\+1)|1)? ?\(?(\d{3})\)?[ .-]?(\d{3})[ .-]?(\d{4})( ?(ext\.? ?|x)(\d*))?$/);

    phone = phone.trim();
    var results = phoneTest.exec(phone);
    if (results !== null && results.length > 8) {

        return "(" + results[3] + ") " + results[4] + "-" + results[5] + (typeof results[8] !== "undefined" ? " x" + results[8] : "");

    }
    else {
         return phone;
    }
}
```

It accepts almost all imaginable ways of writing a US phone number. The result is formatted to a standard form of (987) 654-3210 x123

Answer (score 7):

## thinking backwards

Take the last digits only (up to 10) ignoring first "1".

```
function formatUSNumber(entry = '') {
  const match = entry
    .replace(/\D+/g, '').replace(/^1/, '')
    .match(/([^\d]*\d[^\d]*){1,10}$/)[0]
  const part1 = match.length > 2 ? `(${match.substring(0,3)})` : match
  const part2 = match.length > 3 ? ` ${match.substring(3, 6)}` : ''
  const part3 = match.length > 6 ? `-${match.substring(6, 10)}` : ''    
  return `${part1}${part2}${part3}`
}
```

example input / output as you type

```
formatUSNumber('+1333')
// (333)

formatUSNumber('333')
// (333)

formatUSNumber('333444')
// (333) 444

formatUSNumber('3334445555')
// (333) 444-5555
```

Answer (score 4):

## 2021

[libphonenumber-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js)

Example

```
import parsePhoneNumber from 'libphonenumber-js'

const phoneNumber = parsePhoneNumber('+12133734253')

phoneNumber.formatInternational() === '+1 213 373 4253'
phoneNumber.formatNational() === '(213) 373-4253'
phoneNumber.getURI() === 'tel:+12133734253'
```

Comment: This does look like a very functional library! 145kB though, which is a tad heavy if you're just looking for something to format the number. Just something to keep in mind for anyone else looking.

Answer (score 3):

Based on David Baucum's answer - here is a version that trys to improve auto-replacement "as you type" for example in a React onChange event handler:

```
function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
  const cleanNum = phoneNumber.toString().replace(/\D/g, '');
  const match = cleanNum.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})$/);
  if (match) {
    return '(' + match[1] + ') ' + (match[2] ? match[2] + "-" : "") + match[3];
  }
  return cleanNum;
}

//...

onChange={e => setPhoneNum(formatPhoneNumber(e.target.value))}
```

It will insert (###) as soon as there are 3 numbers and then it will keep following the RegEx until it looks like this (###) ###-####

Answer (score 2):

I've extended [David Baucum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52544510/1076872) to include support for extensions up to 4 digits in length. It also includes the parentheses requested in the original question. This formatting will work as you type in the field.

```
phone = phone.replace(/\D/g, '');
const match = phone.match(/^(\d{1,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,4})$/);
if (match) {
    phone = `(${match[1]}${match[2] ? ') ' : ''}${match[2]}${match[3] ? '-' : ''}${match[3]}${match[4] ? ' x' : ''}${match[4]}`;
}
return phone;
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of these have issues when the user tries to backspace over the delimiters, particularly from the middle of the string.

Here's a jquery solution that handles that, and also makes sure the cursor stays in the right place as you edit:

```
//format text input as phone number (nnn) nnn-nnnn
$('.myPhoneField').on('input', function (e){
    var $phoneField = e.target;
    var cursorPosition = $phoneField.selectionStart;
    var numericString = $phoneField.value.replace(/\D/g, '').substring(0, 10);

    // let user backspace over the '-'
    if (cursorPosition === 9 && numericString.length > 6) return;

    // let user backspace over the ') '
    if (cursorPosition === 5 && numericString.length > 3) return;
    if (cursorPosition === 4 && numericString.length > 3) return;

    var match = numericString.match(/^(\d{1,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})$/);
    if (match) {
        var newVal = '(' + match[1];
        newVal += match[2] ? ') ' + match[2] : '';
        newVal += match[3] ? '-' + match[3] : '';

        // to help us put the cursor back in the right place
        var delta = newVal.length - Math.min($phoneField.value.length, 14);      
        $phoneField.value = newVal;
        $phoneField.selectionEnd = cursorPosition + delta;
    } else {
        $phoneField.value = '';        
    }
})
```

Comment: The question and other previous answers are not about "while the user is typing". Just about taking an input and giving a formatted ouptut.

Comment: I know this wasn't specifically what the OP asked for, but it is exactly what I was looking for, and this works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner (formatted for readability) that works for **both** international and US phone numbers:

```js
const formatUSAndInternationalNumber = (phone) => phone
  .replace(/\D/g, '')
  .replace(/(\d*)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/, (s, a, b, c, d) => `+${a} (${b}) ${c}-${d}`)
  .replace(/\+(1\b|\s)\s*/, '');
```

US phone numbers are turned domestic by dropping the `+1` prefix.

Example:

```
formatUSAndInternationalNumber('1231231234')
  -> '(123) 123-1234'
formatUSAndInternationalNumber('11231231234')
  -> '(123) 123-1234'

formatUSAndInternationalNumber('491231231234')
  -> '+49 (123) 123-1234'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = "(123) 456-7890".replace(/[^\d]/g, ""); //This strips all characters that aren't digits
if (numbers.length != 10) //wrong format
    //handle error
var phone = "(" + numbers.substr(0, 3) + ") " + numbers.substr(3, 3) + "-" + numbers.substr(6); //Create format with substrings
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one that will accept both phone numbers and phone numbers with extensions.

```
function phoneNumber(tel) {
var toString = String(tel),
    phoneNumber = toString.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""),
    countArrayStr = phoneNumber.split(""),
    numberVar = countArrayStr.length,
    closeStr = countArrayStr.join("");
if (numberVar == 10) {
    var phone = closeStr.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1.$2.$3"); // Change number symbols here for numbers 10 digits in length. Just change the periods to what ever is needed.
} else if (numberVar > 10) {
    var howMany = closeStr.length,
        subtract = (10 - howMany),
        phoneBeginning = closeStr.slice(0, subtract),
        phoneExtention = closeStr.slice(subtract),
        disX = "x", // Change the extension symbol here
        phoneBeginningReplace = phoneBeginning.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1.$2.$3"), // Change number symbols here for numbers greater than 10 digits in length. Just change the periods and to what ever is needed. 
        array = [phoneBeginningReplace, disX, phoneExtention],
        afterarray = array.splice(1, 0, " "),
        phone = array.join("");

} else {
    var phone = "invalid number US number";
}
return phone;
}

phoneNumber("1234567891"); // Your phone number here
```

Answer (score 1):

For all international Phone numbers with country code upto 3 digits, we can change the original answer a little bit as below.
For first match instead of looking for '1' we should look for 1-3 digits.

```
 export const formatPhoneNumber = (phoneNumberString) => {
  var cleaned = ('' + phoneNumberString).replace(/\D/g, '');
  var match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{1,3}|)?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
   if (match) {
    var intlCode = (match[1] ? `+${match[1]} ` : '');
    return [intlCode, '(', match[2], ') ', match[3], '-', match[4]].join('');
  }
  return null;
}
console.log( formatPhoneNumber('16464765278') )//+1 (646) 476-5278
console.log( formatPhoneNumber('+2549114765278')) //+254 (911) 476-5278
console.log( formatPhoneNumber('929876543210') )//+92 (987) 654-3210
```

Fulfils my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For US Phone Numbers

```
/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/
```

Let’s divide this regular expression in smaller fragments to make is easy to understand.

- `/^\(?`: Means that the phone number may begin with an optional `(`.
- `(\d{3})`: After the optional `(` there must be 3 numeric digits. If the phone number does not have a `(`, it must start with 3 digits. E.g. `(308` or `308`.
- `\)?`: Means that the phone number can have an optional `)` after first 3 digits.
- `[- ]?`: Next the phone number can have an optional hyphen (`-`) after `)` if present or after first 3 digits.
- `(\d{3})`: Then there must be 3 more numeric digits. E.g `(308)-135` or `308-135` or `308135`
- `[- ]?`: After the second set of 3 digits the phone number can have another optional hyphen (`-`). E.g `(308)-135-` or `308-135-` or `308135-`
- `(\d{4})$/`: Finally, the phone number must end with four digits. E.g `(308)-135-7895` or `308-135-7895` or `308135-7895` or `3081357895`.

  Reference :

http://www.zparacha.com/phone_number_regex/

Comment: Copying stuff from other websites and then not even posting the link is pretty bad behaviour: http://www.zparacha.com/phone_number_regex/

Comment: I am sorry, I had no idea that we have to post link. I thought we have to just provide answers to the queries posted.

Comment: It is **never** ok to make another someones work look like your own. Remember it for next time that there is nothing wrong with posting links, but copying (especially without providing a link) is not. And you always have the option of editing your answer.

Comment: Downvoted because the author did not answer how to **replace** the phone number as the author requested.

Comment: upvoted because author has now provided link, this solution has clear explanation and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this functions to check valid phone numbers and normalize them:

```
let formatPhone = (dirtyNumber) => {
 return dirtyNumber.replace(/\D+/g, '').replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
}

let isPhone = (phone) => {
   //normalize string and remove all unnecessary characters
   phone = phone.replace(/\D+/g, '');
   return phone.length == 10? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above are superior, especially if using Java, and encountering more numbers with more than 10 digits such as the international code prefix or additional extension numbers. This solution is basic (I'm a beginner in the regex world) and designed with US Phone numbers in mind and is only useful for strings with just 10 numbers with perhaps some formatting characters, or perhaps no formatting characters at all (just 10 numbers). As such I would recomend this solution only for semi-automatic applications. I Personally prefer to store numbers as just 10 numbers without formatting characters, but also want to be able to convert or clean phone numbers to the standard format normal people and apps/phones will recognize instantly at will.

I came across this post looking for something I could use with a text cleaner app that has PCRE Regex capabilities (but no java functions). I will post this here for people who could use a simple pure Regex solution that could work in a variety of text editors, cleaners, expanders, or even some clipboard managers. I personally use Sublime and TextSoap. This solution was made for Text Soap as it lives in the menu bar and provides a drop-down menu where you can trigger text manipulation actions on what is selected by the cursor or what's in the clipboard.

My approach is essentially two substitution/search and replace regexes. Each substitution search and replace involves two regexes, one for search and one for replace.

**Substitution/ Search & Replace #1**

- The first substitution/ search & replace strips non-numeric numbers from an otherwise 10-digit number to a 10-digit string.

First Substitution/ **Search** Regex: `\D`

- This search string matches all characters that is *not* a digit.

First Substitution/ **Replace** Regex: "" (nothing, not even a space)

- Leave the substitute field completely blank, no white space should exist including spaces. This will result in all matched non-digit characters being deleted. You should have gone in with 10 digits + formatting characters prior this operation and come out with 10 digits sans formatting characters.

**Substitution/ Search & Replace #2**

- The second substitution/search and replace *search* part of the operation captures groups for area code `$1`, a capture group for the second set of three numbers `$2`, and the last capture group for the last set of four numbers `$3`. The regex for the *substitute* portion of the operation inserts US phone number formatting in between the captured group of digits.

Second Substitution/ **Search** Regex: `(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})`

Second Substitution/ **Replace** Regex: `\($1\) $2\-$3`

- The backslash `\` escapes the special characters `(`, `)` ,  (<-whitespace), and `-` since we are inserting them between our captured numbers in capture groups `$1`, `$2`, & `$3` for US phone number formatting purposes.
- In TextSoap I created a custom cleaner that includes the two substitution operation actions, so in practice it feels identical to executing a script. I'm sure this solution could be improved but I expect complexity to go up quite a bit. An improved version of this solution is welcomed as a learning experience if anyone wants to add to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function phoneFormat(value) {
    value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (value.length < 2) {
        return value.replace(/(\d{1})/, '+$1');
    } 
    if (value.length < 5) {
        return value.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{1,3})/, '+$1 ($2');
    } 
    if (value.length < 8) {
        return value.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{1,3})/, '+$1 ($2) $3');
    }
    if (value.length < 10) {
        return value.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{1,2})/, '+$1 ($2) $3-$4');
    } 
    return value.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{1,2})/, '+$1 ($2) $3-$4-$5');
}

// Set the event and format the field value in real time
document.getElementById('input-phone').addEventListener('input', e => {
    e.target.value = phoneFormat(e.target.value);
});
```

or

```
phoneFormat('88002345678'); // +8 (800) 234-56-78
phoneFormat('qwerty895'); // +8 (95
phoneFormat('89545544'); // +8 (954) 554-4
```