# Phone Number I/O formatting

Tags: javascript, html

Using suggested code from the answer to [Regular Expression to reformat a US phone number in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358084/regular-expression-to-reformat-a-us-phone-number-in-javascript), I'm attempting to output formatted phone numbers that come from user input in the form of a typical HTML form. I know the functions for formatting the numbers are working properly, because if you pass through an explicit argument to the function, it works. So my thought was maybe my input wasn't coming in as a string. But, I've tried converting via String() and toString() but have had no luck. Am I missing something?

To test the formatting functions, all you have to do is to create variables with a phone number string as values and pass those through as the function arguments in place of *officePhone* and *cellPhone*.

**Note: You have to click the submit button under the form to run the script.**

```js
function populate(){ 

 var officePhone = document.getElementsByName("input_office_phone")[0],
  cellPhone = document.getElementsByName("input_cell_phone")[0];
 
 
 function formatOfficePhone(officePhoneString) {
    var cleaned = ('' + officePhoneString).replace(/\D/g, '')
    var match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/)
    if (match) {
      return match[1] + '.' + match[2] + '.' + match[3]
    }
    return null
 }
 
 
 function formatCellPhone(cellPhoneString) {
    var cleaned = ('' + cellPhoneString).replace(/\D/g, '')
    var match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/)
    if (match) {
      return match[1] + '.' + match[2] + '.' + match[3]
    }
    return null
 }
 
 
 

 document.getElementById("office_phone").innerHTML = formatOfficePhone(officePhone);
 document.getElementById("cell_phone").innerHTML = formatCellPhone(cellPhone);

 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<strong>***INPUT***</strong><br>
<form>
  Office Phone:
  <input type="text" name="input_office_phone">
  <br>
  Cell Phone:
  <input type="text" name="input_cell_phone">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onClick="populate()">Submit</button>
</form>
<br>
<strong>***OUTPUT***</strong><br>
<strong>office:</strong> <span id="office_phone"></span> <br>
<strong>cell:</strong> <span id="cell_phone"></span> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you're getting a reference to the input elements `input_office_phone` and `input_cell_phone`, but not the value contained within. To resolve this, you need to get the `.value` of the element, like in the example below.

Some other cleanup:

- You had two identical functions for formatting both phone numbers instead of reusing the same function. I've cleaned that up below.
- You were declaring your format functions within the `populate()` function. Ideally you don't want to have functions nested inside other functions, so I've separated them below.

Hope this helps!

```js
function formatPhone(number) {
  var cleaned = ('' + number).replace(/\D/g, '')
  var match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/)
  if (match) {
    return match[1] + '.' + match[2] + '.' + match[3]
  }
  return null
}

function populate() {
  var officePhone = document.getElementsByName("input_office_phone")[0].value,
    cellPhone = document.getElementsByName("input_cell_phone")[0].value;

  document.getElementById("office_phone").innerHTML = formatPhone(officePhone);
  document.getElementById("cell_phone").innerHTML = formatPhone(cellPhone);
}
```

```html
<strong>***INPUT***</strong><br>
<form>
  Office Phone:
  <input type="text" name="input_office_phone">
  <br> Cell Phone:
  <input type="text" name="input_cell_phone">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onClick="populate()">Submit</button>
</form>
<br>
<strong>***OUTPUT***</strong><br>
<strong>office:</strong> <span id="office_phone"></span> <br>
<strong>cell:</strong> <span id="cell_phone"></span>
```

Comment: Excellent! That is exactly what the problem was. Thanks for the help and some clean-up tips. I had split the function into two because I was testing a few formatting variations...forgot to go ahead and bring it all back together. As for the nested functions, I'm more used to some other languages where nested functions are acceptable and the norm, so I always forget its not preferable in JS. Thanks again, mate!