# Inserting character to input as phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I fix this code to apply the `-` only after 3 first number, so the output looks like

> 778-2299

not `778-229-9` as you can see the code is adding the `-` after every 3 digits

```js
$('.phonenumber').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  if (foo.length > 0) {
    foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,3}', 'g')).join("-");
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="phonenumber" maxlength="8"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to reformat a US phone number in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358084/regular-expression-to-reformat-a-us-phone-number-in-javascript)

Comment: overuse of regular expressions...just check if the length is 3 and add a dash

Comment: I suggest using an input mask component. There are a bazillion out there.

Comment: @MonaCoder: remember that suggestions about duplicates here are given in good faith, and are helpful. It is not advisable to retaliate with an unfriendly or hostile message - your assumption that the other post is not a duplicate _may_ be incorrect. I have flagged your message as unfriendly, in order to encourage a civil and professional tone. There will not be an immediate consequence to this flag, but nevertheless, please do not collect too many of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

> [.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace): ...method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.

```js
$('.phonenumber').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  if (foo.length > 0) {
    foo = foo.replace(/(\d{3})(\d*)/, '$1-$2');
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="phonenumber" maxlength="8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `g` flag? That means "globally search for the matching pattern", but you only want it to match the first, so you don't want that flag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why regex is required. Just use good old `substring`.

<sup>I also changed it to use the `input` event, as it is more consistent in when it fires (after the `value` has been updated)</sup>

```js
$('.phonenumber').on('input', function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  if (foo.length === 7) {
    foo = `${foo.substring(0,3)}-${foo.substring(3)}`;
    // or if you're kickin it old skool:
    // foo = foo.substring(0,3) + "-" + foo.substring(3);
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="phonenumber" maxlength="8"/>
```