# Phone number input field in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input field in my html form to enter phone number in US format. i want a format to appear in the field when it is focused. I want to replicate the phone number field in this form:
https://www.envoymortgage.com/contact-us/

my current code is:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="lname">Phone Number: <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phname" placeholder="Full Number (incl. prefix)" name="phno" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand wanting to do something, but what have you tried to accomplish it?

Comment: Also, what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: I have done nothing yet. I don't know where to start.
Here's my current code:
<div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="lname">Phone Number: <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">          
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phname" placeholder="Full Number (incl. prefix)" name="phno" required>
                  </div>
                </div>

Comment: plenty of libraries out there that do it

Comment: Please go here its already answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358084/regular-expression-to-reformat-a-us-phone-number-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Jquery masked input plugin to achieve that.
just embed the masked script

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js'></script>
```

After that call the mask function:

```js
$('#phname').mask('(999) 999-9999');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
  <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="lname">Phone Number: <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phname" placeholder="Full Number (incl. prefix)" name="phno" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @EshwarHebbur Can you marked as correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two fields, one are used for inputs, another reflex that inputs into the format that you want. 
You need two javascript, one for the reflex, another for validate the inputs. You only want to accept numbers, not letters or special characters