# How can i apply Phone Number Format to a Cell in Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was wondering how one would go to apply a format of north american 10 digit in
a cell of a angular material table. if it is a 10 digit number i want to display as 
(XXX) XXX-XXXX otherwise the non-formatted number.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="number">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef width="200px"> Phone Number </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.number}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Now this one slices the 10 digits as i expected

```
 ({{element.number |slice:0:3}}) {{element.number |slice:3:6}} - {{element.number |slice:6:10}}
```

But i am still not able to combine this with the

```
element.number.length ===10 ?
```

Since this seems to be quite messy, is there another way to format the number in a function before it gets passed as the element to the table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression to reformat a US phone number in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358084/regular-expression-to-reformat-a-us-phone-number-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of this [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8358141/9822083), would this be of any use to you?

You can pass in your un-formatted phone number as a string to this function, and display the value in the HTML like so:

Your js:

```
function formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumberString) {
  var cleaned = ('' + phoneNumberString).replace(/\D/g, '');
  var match = cleaned.match(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/);
  if (match) {
    this.formattedNumber = '(' + match[1] + ') ' + match[2] + '-' + match[3];
  }
  this.formattedNumber = null;
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="number">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef width="200px"> Phone Number </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{formattedNumber}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a use-case for a pipe. You can give pass the number into the pipe and output it in a format that you see fit. I'm not sure if there is a built-in pipe for phone numbers, and if not, you can [build one following along with the angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes).

In the end, in your Angular Html template, it will look something like this

```html
<div>{{phoneNumber | my-phonenumber-pipe}}</div>
```