# Intl.NumberFormat() constructor with phone numbers

Tags: javascript

So I'm new to this, and just wondering if this method would also format phone numbers? Didn't see it on the docs, but just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: Their is No built in feature in js for formatting phone no. You need to use regular expression to achieve that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression to reformat a US phone number in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358084/regular-expression-to-reformat-a-us-phone-number-in-javascript)

Comment: It sort of does, but was just wondering if that method worked because it supports many countries, making a regex for us, but not other countries wouldn't seem like such a good solution