# React native typescript : adding automatic hyphen and mask

Tags: typescript, react-native

I’m doing project in React Native.

1. How can i add hyphen automatically while typing the social security numbers like `123456789` to `123-45-6789`.
2. How can i mask the specific number into any symbol from left or right like `123456789` to `xxx-45-6789` or `123-45-xxxx`.

My code :

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

import { StyleProp, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';

import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { Layout, Input, Icon } from '_atoms';

import { fillColor } from '_utils';

import { Label } from '_organisms';

import { style } from '../style';



let Mask = ({ attribute, data, formOptions, disable }: any) => {



const { name, required, title, info, placeHolder, validationRegEx, defaultValue, canUpdate,

        unique, splitBy, pattern, numOfSplits, position, mask, length, maskBy,

        ...others } = attribute;



    const { control }: any = formOptions || {};



    let regEx = /^(?!(000|666|9))\d{3}-?(?!(00))\d{2}-?(?!(0000))\d{4}$/



    const { theme } = useSelector((state: any) => state.app);



    let color = fillColor(disable, theme);



    

    return (

        <Layout style={style.container as StyleProp<ViewStyle>}>

            <>

                <Label isRequired={required} title={title} description={info} />

            </>

            <Controller

                control={control}

                render={({ field, fieldState }: any) => {

                    let { onChange, value } = field || {};

                    let { error } = fieldState || {};

                    let { message } = error || {};



                    return (

                        <Input

                            placeholder={placeHolder}

                            testID={name}

                            disabled={disable}

                            onChangeText={(value: any) => { onChange(value); }}

                            value={value ? value : ''}

                            status={error ? 'danger' : 'primary'}

                            caption={error ? message || 'Required' : ''}

                            accessoryRight={(props: any) => {

                                if (value) {

                                    return (

                                        <Icon

                                            {...props}

                                            fill={color}

                                            name={'close'}

                                            disabled={disable}

                                            onPress={() => onChange('')}

                                        />

                                    );

                                } else return <></>;

                            }}

                        />

                    )



                }}

                name={name}

                rules={{

                    required: required,

                    pattern: {

                        value: validationRegEx || regEx,

                        message: 'Enter a valid SSN',

                    },

                    maxLength: {

                        value: 11,

                        message: "SSN length should be < 9",

                      },

                }}

                defaultValue={data || defaultValue || ''}

            />

        </Layout>

    );

};



export default Mask;
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with React Native. Look into regular expression `group` and `match` and `replace`. SOmething like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8358141/298455