# Formatting a long number as phone number

Tags: javascript

I have a number from my database like this '15555555555'.
I need to convert it into this +1 (555) 555-5555.

My current code formats it to (155) 555-5555 and I'm attempting to fix it to the correct format.

Here is my code:

```
const formatPhoneNumber = () => {
        // convert the raw number to x (xxx) xxx-xxx format
        const x = user.phone && user.phone.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
        return !x[2] ? x[1] : `(${x[1]}) ${x[2]}${x[3] ? `-${x[3]}` : ''}`;
      };
```

Comment: You can check the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358084/regular-expression-to-reformat-a-us-phone-number-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution to simply remove the first number in the string and then I'll simply add it back in via text in the html. However I will need to add to this to account for other countries phone numbers. But I plan on doing that by writing in some if statements based on the country that is pulled from my database.

```
const formatPhoneNumber = () => {
        const PhoneNumber = user.phone.substring(1);
        // convert the raw number to (xxx) xxx-xxx format
        const x = PhoneNumber && PhoneNumber .replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
        return !x[2] ? x[1] : `(${x[1]}) ${x[2]}${x[3] ? `-${x[3]}` : ''}`;
      };
```