# How to format phone number in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, format, phone-number

I created a form field in HTML, and I want to auto-format the phone number input to look like (123) 456-7890.

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<form>
<div class="sc-formfield-input">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="Phone" name="Phone" data-field-type="Phone"  placeholder="Phone" ><i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i></div>
</div>
</form>
```

How do I write the JavaScript to format the phone number the way I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression to reformat a US phone number in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358084/regular-expression-to-reformat-a-us-phone-number-in-javascript)

Comment: I see JavaScript examples t solve this, but where in the html do I add the JavaScript? I created a <script></script> and inserted the JS into it, but how do I get that script to connect to the phone input field in my html?

Comment: you probably want it to happen on the `change` event of the `input`. can you add the js function for completeness? then you can hook it using `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

Using the function of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8358141/4965547), you could achieve what you want by appending this in your `script` tag:

```js
document.getElementById('Phone').addEventListener('focusout', function() {
    event.target.value = formatPhoneNumber(event.target.value);
});
```

You can also use the `change` event instead of `focusout` as
IT goldman suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code as reference and change value as soon as number is input.

```js
function RecordChange() {
    let number = document.getElementById("phone_number_field").value;
    //console.log(number);
    if(number.length > 10) {
        document.getElementById("Show_Warning").innerHTML = "invalid phone number"
        document.getElementById("phone_number_field").style.borderColor = 'red';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("Show_Warning").innerHTML = ""
        document.getElementById("phone_number_field").style.borderColor = 'black';
    }
    if(
        number.length === 10
    ) {
        let targetvalue = "(" + number.slice(0, 3) + ")-" + number.slice(3, 7) + "-" + number.slice(7, 10)
        console.log(targetvalue);
        document.getElementById("phone_number_field").value = targetvalue;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<html>
    <title>Header</title>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        Body Starts : 
        <div>
            <p>Phone Number : </p>
            <input type="text" id="phone_number_field" oninput="RecordChange()">
            <p id = "Show_Warning"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is just a dummy code, but function you can use for changing number format as required.