# Formatting phone number in the thymeleaf html page

Tags: javascript, html, spring-thymeleaf

I have a list of phone numbers in different formats like '1234567-8901', '49123456 6544', '861234567899', and lots of other formats also. I want to format the phone number in the format like for example lets take USA phone number, it should display like '+ 1 xxx-xxx-xxxx'. We are using thymeleaf and js for implementing this.Please tell me the step by step process on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to solve this. I would suggest taking a look at this stack overflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8358141/19184713